# Fixing an ErrorException include_once(geoPHP.inc) in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to use GeoPHP to calculate polygons.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class AreaController extends Controller
{
    public function show(){


            include_once"geoPHP.inc";

                // Polygon WKT example
                $polygon = geoPHP::load('POLYGON((1 1,5 1,5 5,1 5,1 1),(2 2,2 3,3 3,3 2,2 2))','wkt');
                $area = $polygon->getArea();
                $centroid = $polygon->getCentroid();
                $centX = $centroid->getX();
                $centY = $centroid->getY();

                print "This polygon has an area of ".$area." and a centroid with X=".$centX." and Y=".$centY;

                // MultiPoint json example
                print "<br/>";
                $json = 
                '{
                   "type": "MultiPoint",
                   "coordinates": [
                       [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0]
                   ]
                }';

                $multipoint = geoPHP::load($json, 'json');
                $multipoint_points = $multipoint->getComponents();
                $first_wkt = $multipoint_points[0]->out('wkt');

                print "This multipoint has ".$multipoint->numGeometries()." points. The first point has a wkt representation of ".$first_wkt;
             }

}
```

Upon executing my app, it displays this error in the browser.

[image]

Comment: use this (use Geo;) in your controller and remove  include_once"geoPHP.inc"; now instead of geoPHP use Geo::